# Hyperledger Fabric Deployment with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am confused about setting up the **kafka nodes in production environment**. I know, the Hyperledger **community suggests Kafka to be setup at the joint venture** of multiple organizations. As, the community prefers to keep all the Kafka and Zookeeper nodes at a single datacenter for a better performance.

But, I can't have a joint venture of all the orgs. **Can Kafka, Zookeeper and Orderer nodes be distributed over multiple orgs?** For an instance:

[image]

Suppose if there are two orgs, they can host the following:

- Each Org has it's own MSP
- Each Org has 4 Peers
- Kafka cluster is shared. i.e. Org1 hosts 2 Kafka and 2 Zookeeper nodes, and Org 2 hosts, 2 kafka and 1 zookeeper node.
- Each Org has 2 Orderer.

Comment: You could have independent Kafka clusters in each, then share data between them using MirrorMaker, for example. You definitely should not use an even number or one zookeepers only, though

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for sharing your thoughts. But,I am more concerned about the security of the nodes. Kafka would store all the events which needs to be used to generate a Block. If the Kafka nodes would be hosted by the Orgs individually, they might change the events in any way and we won't ever get to know as Peers just validate on ReadSet and not the writeSet. I can always go to Kafka as I know all the security layer of it,use TLS certs of any orderer hosted by me and change any writeset value for any readset. The transaction will still go through as it has a valid ReadSet and stores junk

Comment: Kafka is append only, so I'm not sure what you mean by "change the events"... Plus, I have no familiarity with Hyperledger except for the documentation page about Kafka setup... If security is the issue, then sure, you can use `SSL_SASL` for Kafka

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear,  I am new to kafka. I am just thinking about a scenario where an event is pushed to the queue. Somehow, we manage to get to the queue and change the event. i.e I have pushed the value as 'A' but I changed the value to 'B'. Is it possible by any means in Kafka? Or Is kafka immutable event queue where you can't change any event which is already pushed to the queue?

Comment: It is indeed immutable. Assuming you're not giving root SSH access to the brokers where the data is actually stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distributed fabric network deployment should fine tune the trade-offs between division of responsibility and trust between the organizations hosting the services. As suggested in the question, peer organizations sharing the hosting of kafka-zookeeper cluster and ordering service nodes may lead to scalability and trust issues as the size of consortium grows. Following are two major concerns:

1. zookeepers are required to be deployed in odd numbers to avoid split
   brain problems and deployments >=7 is not recommended. If peer
   organizations take the responsibility of hosting zookeepers as well,
   the solution will not scale once the zookeeper ensemble maxes out
   and new organizations keep coming in.
2. On the other hand, hosting OSNs within the same organization as the
   peers is discouraged as well. This is due to the default block
   validation policy delimited by fabric which allows any valid
   certificate of the ordering organization, in this case the one
   hosting peer nodes as well, to sign blocks. This essentially means that a block signed by using any valid certificate generated by an organization hosting a variety of services, including the ordering service, will pass the validation. So,

   > [if an organization is acting both in an ordering and application role,
   >   then this policy should be updated to restrict block signers to the
   >   subset of certificates authorized for ordering](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/Fabric-FAQ.html)